# Debian 6, Clean Install - Where to start?

Tags: linux, debian

I've never used Debian before, but I have to run Debian 6 for a project and I was given instructions to install the dependencies.

It's a clean Debian 6 install on an Amazon Web Services instance.

I'm supposed to enter this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install exactimage
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install automake
```

But all I get is:

```
sudo: command not found
```

I tried:

```
apt-get install libpng12-dev
```

But it gave me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpng12-dev
```

Please help a hopeless newbie like myself! (We all have to start somewhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `sudo` if you are login in as a non-root user.

Seeing as apt-get didn't complain, you must be logged in as root.  You'll need to update the repositories first:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libpng12-dev
```

Comment: also, debian doesn't have sudo set up by default. ubuntu does, and sets the first user to have the rights needed to do adminny things. If @Alasdair wanted to use sudo, he'd need to set it up with visudo

Comment: (after installing it with `apt-get install sudo`)